# How to change onclick attribute on html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a progress bar and want to change it's `data-pro-bar-percent` attribute value from `80` to `100` when I click a link.

The attribute change should be as follows:
`data-pro-bar-percent="80"` --> `data-pro-bar-percent="100"`

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Click Link</a>
<div class="pro-bar-container color-green-sea">
    <div class="pro-bar bar-100 color-turquoise" data-pro-bar-percent="30" data-pro-bar-delay="4000">
        <div class="pro-bar-candy candy-ltr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need jQuery's `attr()` if you're using jQuery.

Comment: Be sure to give that `<a>` tag an ID to be able to select it properly in Javascript.

Comment: Will the percent always change from 80 to 100, or are those just sample starting and ending amounts?

Comment: @Joe Confusion will arise when more than one element contains the class `button`. Just a foresight into what may happen.

Answer (score 5):

Links are not buttons! Use buttons!

Use the DOM's `setAttribute` method to alter the data attribute. This is tricky though, you can either grab the percent element by its classname (if it shares a class name with another element, you may want to use `this.children.children.setAttribute()`) so grab the closest nested child you want.

Simply set the link/button element an `eventListener` (if it's in a form, a button acts like a submit button by default, so you may need to prevent the default action), and give it a function to change the data attribute.

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>

var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click",function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pro-bar")[0].setAttribute("data-pro-bar-percent","100");
}, false);
```

As @rlemon commented, `getElementsByClassName` [lacks the support](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName) that `querySelector` [does](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector), so you should use that instead.

```
document.querySelector(".pro-bar").setAttribute("data-pro-bar-percent","100");
```

Comment: QSA has better support over getElementsByClassName FYI. The performance his is negligible. and if you only need the first match querySelector and you don't need the [0]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` to get the current data value and then set it as well. Much more efficient.

### http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var current = $('.pro-bar').data("pro-bar-percent");
    $('.pro-bar').data("pro-bar-percent", current += 20);
});
```

Comment: +1 The `data` attribute in this case is indeed more appropriate than a generic class

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery, first give an id to your link:

```
<a class="button" id="btnLink" href="#">Click Link</a>
```

Now, use this, if you directly want to change the value of data-pro-bar-percent to 100.

```
$("#btnLink").on("click",function(){ 
    $(".pro-bar .bar-100 .color-turquoise").attr("data-pro-bar-percent","100");
});
```

If you just want to increment the value of the current bar by 20 then use this:

```
$("#btnLink").on("click",function(){ 
    var targetEle = $(".pro-bar .bar-100 .color-turquoise");
    var currentBar = parseInt(targetEle.attr("data-pro-bar-percent"))+20; // whatever value you want to increment with.

    targetEle.attr("data-pro-bar-percent",currentBar);
});
```

Hope this helps